# Unable to insert() struct into unordered_set

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, std

I cannot insert items into my unordered set. What is going on?

```
typedef struct node_t
{
    char s[SIZE];
    char blank;     //position of blank tile
    char g,h;
    int depth;      //Depth of node for IDA*
}NODE;
```

...

```
NODE CurrentNode;
unordered_set<NODE> seen;

seen.insert(CurrentNode);
```

Throws the following error:

Error   3   error C2678: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const NODE' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler is telling you what's going on: the implementation of unordered_set **requires** that you define an `operator==()` for `NODE`.  BTW: you also have to define a `hash()` function.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined no comparison operator `==`, nor have you arranged for it to be hashed. (also, `MAGIC_BUFFER_SIZE` `char` and `typedef struct`? Really? Did you learn C++ or C?)

Comment: The first code snippet is not my code, but code I was given as part of the assignment.